# char Array in C++ is not functioning properly

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I am coding a C++ program using char array.But i think it is giving problems.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long int t;
    cin>>t;
    char total[500],a[500],b[500];
    cin>>total;
    int len=strlen(total);
    //cout<<strlen(total);
    for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++){
        a[i]=total[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++){
        b[i]=total[i];
    }
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

It is not printing the arrays. But when i commented out

```
/*for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++){
    b[i]=total[i];
}*/
```

it is printing array a as expected. What is the problem here?

Comment: Without a clear description of what you expect to get, the only thing we can say is "Yup, works as written here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arrays are not NULL-terminated. If I add `a[len/2]=0;` and `b[len/2] = 0;` after the `for` loops, it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks,But how its printing when i commenting the second for loop?

Comment: perhaps there's a null somewhere in the memory itself.

Comment: @adafrwefsefr In prints binary data and Ideone fails to read it